# Открыть .txt файл, занятый другой программой

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть ли какая нибудь возможность парсить .txt файл если он занят другой программой?
Какая разница между `ReadAllText` и `FileStream`. Когда пытаюсь считать файл, ошибка `"Файл занят другим процессом"`

Читаю файл так

```
foreach (string item in PathToFiles)
{
    string srt = @item;
    data += File.ReadAllText(srt);
}
```

Comment: Если вы его даже в Notepad++ открыть не можете, и если программа, блокирующая файл не ваша, то нет. Такой возможности нет.

Comment: @aepot это очень печально. В файл почти каждые 1-2 секунды добавляются строки.Думал через `FileStream` как то можно. Сам по себе файл могу открыть

Comment: если сам по себе файл открыть можешь - то открывай только с правами чтения и проблем не будет

Comment: Если можете открыть, то можно. Добавьте в вопрос всю необъодимую информацию, чтобы из вас ее не приходилось вытягивать в комментариях. Вы же как то поняли, что у вас проблема, наверное код какой-то написали. Почему не добавили его в вопрос, чтобы сложнее было догадаться, о чем речь? Ошибка возникает, какая? В какой строке?

Comment: @Andrew А можете объяснить разницу между `FileStream` и `File.ReadAllText`

Comment: @GRAMOTEYTV технически разницы нет, но `FileStream` можно более детально настроить `FileShare` при вызове конструктора.

Comment: `.ReadAllText` в один заход открывает весь файл и считывает в оперативную память. Первый читает потоком данных. Например ты можешь считывать файл блоками по 0,1 кб и обрабатывать паралельно и записывать другим потоком обработанные данные в другое место. Это полезно если тебе нужно обработать текстовый файл размером в гигабайт десять. Потому что хранить 10 гиг текста в оперативке это так себе удовольствие и не каждый компьютер потянет. Но внутри .ReadAllText вероятнее всего реализован внутри именно через FileStream, но считывает весь файл -- поэтому технически разницы нет, как написал  aepot.

Comment: @Andrew `блоками по 0,1 кб` - это вообще не относится к вопросу.

Comment: @aepot именно. Это отдельный вопрос который не относится к основному. Человек спрашивает в чем разница и для чего существуют оба пути

Comment: @Andrew `вероятнее всего реализован` всё что работает в .NET с файлами - реализовано через `FileStream`, без исключений.

Comment: Действительно **другая** программа работает с этим файлом или **ваша** программа из **разных** мест работает с этим файлом? Если первое, то ничего не поделаешь. Если второе, то нужно правильно настроить доступ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File.ReadAllText(path)` пытается получить доступ к файлу, но не может, возможно это связано с особыми параметрами при открытии файла, например там под капотом используется последовательное чтение `FileOptions.SequientialScan`. Но есть более "нежный" способ открыть файл для чтения не задавая лишних опций.

`File.OpenRead(path)` эквивалентен `new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)` - [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openread?view=netframework-4.8).

```cs
foreach (string item in PathToFiles)
{
    using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(item));
    data += sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Протестил, спасибо. Ошибок не замечено

Comment: Всё это немного странно. Смотрите, вот [`File.ReadAllText`](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.FileSystem/System/IO/File.cs,8a84c56a62fd8d45) вызывает [`InternalReadAllText`](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.FileSystem/System/IO/File.cs,b540325bd4967221), который вызывает [`new StreamReader(path, ...)`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/StreamReader.cs,3a059d7881521be7), а он в свою очередь другой [`new StreamReader(path, ...)`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/StreamReader.cs,a820588d8233a829), который открывает файл ...

Comment: ... в [`ValidateArgsAndOpenPath`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/StreamReader.cs,02427b5d9c82923a) через [`new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, ...)`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/StreamReader.cs,212). [`File.OpenRead(path)`](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.FileSystem/System/IO/File.cs,7a7d1c864bec521e) вызывает [`new FileStream(path, ...)` с четырьмя аргументами](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/FileStream.cs,756b978acfa47bc7), который вызывает в конечном итоге тот же конструктор с вроде бы теми же аргументами.

Comment: Внимание, вопрос: а почему есть разница?

Comment: @VladD на гениальность не претендую, но `ReadAllText()` запрашивает `FileOptions.SequientialScan`, быть может быть дело в этом. Надо будет потестить. Вот [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) много всякого понаписано, но однозначных штук, дающих понять, в чем причина, я не нашел.

Comment: @VladD - я на 99,(9)% уверен, что автор чего-то не договаривает. | Только `FileShare` влияет на (не)возможность доступа к файлу.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Угу, и мне почему-то так кажется.